# Compress file using Java Zip class or bash zip command

Tags: java, zip

I have a java app which generates an output file, and that needs to be compressed.
Currently, I am zipping it after the file has been generated using script

```
$ zip <abc.zip> abc
```

Other option is to let Java code compress it using below classes.

```
java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;
```

Now, want to know which is better in terms of compression ratio and time taken ?

Java has advantage of being system independent, but that is ok for me.

Comment: Why don't you test both solutions and measure how much time does it take?

Comment: Thanks Boris for suggestion, but there is no harm in getting help from community.

Answer (score 3):

Java's ZipOutputStream uses the same zlib which is used by zip command as a native library. So in terms of performance they should be equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

I think performance will be same but using

```
zip -9 <abc.zip> abc
```

you can get more compression and you can avoid recursing directory in java by giving `-r` switch in zip command

Answer (score 0):

I would think that you may get a few advantages by wrapping the output stream that writes your file with a `ZipOutputStream`.

Using the script there are several things that you would need to do that you can avoid by writing the zipped stream directly:

- Write out the uncompressed file
- Start an external process (or integrate your Java app with a script)
- Read the uncompressed file in again
- Compress (common to both approaches)
- Write the compressed file (common to both approaches)

Whereas if you use the `ZipOutputStream`

- Write out the result to the stream, which compresses it and writes it to the compressed file
- No headaches with integrating your app with the `zip` script.
- Do you know whether `zip` is available on your deployment platform, here I've got it on Linux but not on AIX)

As always, the solution is to prototype it and carry out testing and then decide which performance/compression is better/acceptable.

Answer (score -1):

i think of course Java is slower, because it is running on the JVM, and not directly to the OS,.
if i were you, i will keep using that script, as long as i have the time to execute it myself,.
i think that is better if you automate it, if you may have no time to execute them everytime,.

Comment: Java implements the ZLIB algorithm, not using the library,.

Comment: You can take a look at java sources and see that it calls native library